# Chrome Extension: Bring data from external API within a chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to do a $.get every time something change on the chrome local storage from a content script. Basically, every time a flag is "undefined" (the flag represents if the extension is active or not) I would want to replace that "undefined" value with the one on the external API. For some reason apparently the $.get never gets executed, none of the alerts or console.logs that are inside the $.get will show up and I'm not getting any console errors too. Just wondering if this has to do with bad management of synchronicity or extension scope.

```
  chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes) => {
      if (changes.isExtensionRunning) {
        isExtensionRunning = changes.isExtensionRunning.newValue;
        if (isExtensionRunning === undefined) {
          //this works I'm getting the console.log
          console.log(`isExtensionRunning is undefined`);
          //this won't work, not even getting the alert
          $.get(EXTENSION_URL, function (data, status) {
            alert('Data: ' + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);
            isExtensionRunning = data.isExtensionRunning;
            checkExtensionStatus(isExtensionRunning);
          });
        } else {
          console.log(`isExtensionRunning no es undefined`);
          checkExtensionStatus(isExtensionRunning);
        }
      }
    });
```

I have tested the API and is working fine, I'm able to post and get the response via:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function (response) {
  userEmail = response.userEmail;
  const EXTENSION_URL =
    'https://apiURL' + userEmail;
  const promise = fetch(EXTENSION_URL);
  promise
    .then(function (response) {
      const processingPromise = response.text();
      return processingPromise;
    })
    .then(function (processedResponse) {
      //This Works
      console.log(`Coming from the API ${processedResponse}`);
    });
});
```

All of these scripts are the chrome extension content scripts:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://xyz*"],
      "css": ["styles/custom.css"],
      "js": [
        "libraries/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
        "scripts/ajaxCalls.js",
        "scripts/configCall.js",
        "scripts/content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

EDIT: After following @wOxxOm advice now I have this:

configCall.js (content script):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ contentScriptQuery: 'isMyExtensionRunning' });
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (
  request,
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  sendResponse({ userEmail: userEmail });
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request);
  if (request.contentScriptQuery == 'isMyExtensionRunning') {
    const EXTENSION_URL =
      'https://xyz/' + userEmail;
    const promise = fetch(EXTENSION_URL);
    promise
      .then(function (response) {
        const processingPromise = response.text();
        return processingPromise;
      })
      .then(function (processedResponse) {
        console.log(`Coming from the API ${processedResponse}`);
      });
  }
});
```

This is working fine, I'm fetching data from the external API and I can console log the response from the background.js. Still (and sorry If I'm asking something obvious), I'm not sure how to make the $.get work from the content.js (another content script) to get this piece of code work:

```
    $.get(EXTENSION_URL, function (data) {
      isExtensionRunning = data.isExtensionRunning;
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });
```

Do I also have to do the $.get from the background.js and then send it as a variable to the content.js ? Many thanks !

Comment: You can't make cross-origin requests in modern Chrome. Do it in the background script and use messaging to deliver data.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm. I have updated the OQ, will really appreciate your feedback.